# ServiceStack license

Tags: servicestack

I've read [ServiceStack license](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/license.txt) and some questions have arisen. The license declares that ServiceStack v4 goes commercial. Will next versions (v4 and higher) be available under FOSS license exceptions?

[Roadmap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Roadmap) states that "We're also planning to introduce our commercial offerings and commercially supported versions of ServiceStack". Does this mean that free ServiceStack version will not get much developer's attention since v4 Release (as MySQL) or become a developer's playground (as Red Hat's Fedora)?

It would be great if the project founders shed some light on the future of ServiceStack.

Comment: Direct Support for ServiceStack [was stopped in July](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106787359118990653189/posts/VyiqqcU38nk). We've only been able to restart Active development on v4 since starting full-time development on it. Here are recent status updates on [ServiceStack v4](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/P3ruPpFZezp) and [OrmLite v4](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/Sbd5113dRrd). v4 is a 'clean break' from v3, which is no longer being actively developed or supported - but is still updated with high-quality external fixes/pull-reqs from the community.

Comment: This question is off-topic. It is not related to a programming challenge/problem. It is also likely to generate opinion rather than factual answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing.